# Set unique rule to a field on update action on yii2 rest

Tags: rest, yii2, yii2-validation

I am creating a rest api with yii2 to create and update user information. Below is the rule function in the model class.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'emailId', 'contactNumber'], 'required'],
            [['name', 'emailId', 'contactNumber'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
            [['emailId', 'username', 'contactNumber'], 'unique'],
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]]
        ];
    }
```

Here I mentioned `emailId`, `username`, `contactNumber` fields should be unique. When I try to create, it is checking whether the field is unique or not. if unique it is throwing the error else it is saving. That is fine.

But when I try to update the value there also it is checking the particular value for the field is unique or not. But it should not be like that. The `unique` validation should not work on `update action`. So I updated the rule with `'on'=>'update'` as like `Yii 1`. Check the below function.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'emailId', 'contactNumber'], 'required'],
            [['name', 'emailId', 'contactNumber'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
            [['emailId', 'username', 'contactNumber'], 'unique', 'on'=>'update'],
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]]
        ];
    }
```

But when i check the [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#unique) there is no option like `on` to check the particular `action`. When i use `'on'=>'update'`, both(while creating and update) places it is not validating. Might be because of the `on`. Just leave that. I need to add `unique` validation for those fields in `create action` only not in `update action`.

So, Please anybody help me with how to add unique validation to those fields only in create action.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set scenario for your `REST` actions in your `ActiveController`:

```
public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        $actions['update']['scenario'] = 'update';
        $actions['create']['scenario'] = 'create';
        return $actions;
    }
```

And then use it in rules:

```
[['emailId', 'username', 'contactNumber'], 'unique', 'on'=>'create']
```

Also you must specify list of active attributes for each scenario in the particular model class:

```
public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios['update'] = ['type', 'title', 'description'];
        $scenarios['create'] = ['type', 'title', 'description', 'affiliate_id'];
        return $scenarios;
    }
```

Comment: now if you update a record you can add a duplicate. That solution does not look correct to me.

Comment: @cebe Looking at validator now - there is check based on PK of model, so simple unique rule should work. As far as i remember this was answer more like how to use scenarios. Thanks for clarification.